# jQuery plugin / JavaScript library to help input date in correct format

Tags: javascript, jquery

Anybody know some jQuery plugin or JavaScript lib to help input date, but using only keyboard ? I'm looking for something that suggests correct format (dots etc) during input.

Something like that would be great:

```
$('input').dateHelper('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into jQuery masked input :)

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#product").mask("9999-99-99",{placeholder:" "});
});
```

[MASKED INPUT PLUGIN](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)